# How to find the last paid bill for every customers present in the Receipt table

Tags: winforms, ms-access-2007, c#-2.0

Table name: receipt

columns:
receipt_id,customer_id,receipt_date,receipt_amount

A customer would have paid many bills. I want to find the details of the last paid bills of every customer in the receipt table. I used nested queries but i am not getting proper results.

```
select customer_id,receipt_date from receipt where receipt_id=(select top 1 receipt_id from receipt order by customer_id desc)
```

I use Access 2007, C#2.0.

Comment: re: "I used nested queries but i am not getting proper results." - Please edit your question to show us what you tried.

Comment: select customer_id,receipt_date from receipt where receipt_id=(select top 1 receipt_id from receipt order by customer_id desc)

Answer (score 1):

To get the details of the latest receipt for each customer you need to start by finding the latest [receipt_date] for each [customer_id]

```sql
SELECT
    customer_id,
    MAX(receipt_date) AS max_receipt_date
FROM receipt
GROUP BY customer_id
```

You can then use that as a component in the query to return the entire [receipt] row for that [customer_id] and date:

```sql
SELECT receipt.*
FROM
    receipt
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            MAX(receipt_date) AS max_receipt_date
        FROM receipt
        GROUP BY customer_id
    ) AS max
        ON max.customer_id = receipt.customer_id
            AND max.max_receipt_date = receipt.receipt_date
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the receipt_id??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM receipt r1
WHERE r1.recipt_date
    =
    (SELECT MAX(receipt_date) FROM receipt r2
         WHERE r2.customer_id = r1.customer_id
    );
```

This solution is using correlated - sub queries.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the records get inserted everytime customer makes the purchase with customer_id remaining same all the time and only receipt_id is different... Then below SQL query should work

select receipt_id , receipt_date
from receipt 
group by customer_id;

U can also add order by receipt_date

Comment: Access won't like that. [receipt_date] would either have to be used in an aggregate function (e.g., MAX()) or included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: how to find the last receipt then??

Comment: by running above query every receipt_id is associated with the latest date.....and by adding order by receipt_date , U get the list of receipts according to the latest date

Comment: "select receipt_id , receipt_date from receipt group by customer_id and order by receipt_date desc" its not working. I am little poor with SQL queries.

Comment: Sorry, no. The query in its present form is simply not valid: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'receipt_id' as part of an aggregate function.'